# Can't deploy Python script with Polygon io Library in Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Python script that works fine locally, but when I test it in Google Cloud Function, I get the following error:

> ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle. This may be the result of using an untrusted builder: failed with status code: 20

I believe Cloud Function doesn't support Polygon.

Here's the code sample:

```py
from polygon import RESTClient
import json
from typing import cast
from urllib3 import HTTPResponse
import datetime

client = RESTClient(api_key="<API_KEY>", trace=False)

maang_companies = ["META", "AAPL", "AMZN", "GOOGL", "NFLX"]

stock_data = {}
def get_stocks_data():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    one_day_prior = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    one_day_prior_str = one_day_prior.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    for stock in maang_companies:
        aggs = cast(
            HTTPResponse,
            client.get_aggs(
                stock,
                1,
                "day",
                one_day_prior_str,
                one_day_prior_str,
                raw=True
            ),
        )

        data = json.loads(aggs.data)
        stock_data[stock] = data
    json_data = json.dumps(stock_data, indent=2)
    return json_data
```

Is there any way to deploy my script into cloud? The initial idea was to deploy code with Cloud Function and trigger after midnight with Pub/Sub and Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: You have a build problem. Did you look in Cloud Logging to find out why?

Comment: It turns out the source file needs to be named 'main.py.' (such a silly mistake). Everything works now

Answer (score 1):

Changing the source file name to "main.py" solved the issue